# Task :app:installDebug FAILED in React Native. App not installing on device

Tags: reactjs, react-native, native

While running the command

```
npx react-native run-android
```

the compilation is completed and app starts installing but it gives the following error :
[Error Here !](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k5tLJ.png)

Tried to clean cache and reinstall but nothing was successful. All other answers didn't worked.

Comment: There must be more about this error above the one you shared, please share that.

Comment: Normally, for example, that would happen if there's a dependency that's not compatible with your phone. But if you could provide more info around the error, that would be helpful

Comment: SOLVED !! Actually the problem was with device's memory. A previous version of app was installed. When I deleted it, the new version got installed. But when i run the command again after some changes, I got the error again. So I found the internal memory was less due to which it's causing problem. The console didn't showed anything related.

Answer (score 0):

If you work with emulator on mac computer, emulator must be manually open before "npx react-native run-android". If you work with physical device you must connect the device via usb. Also device's developer options must be activated. I mean you must see device is active in android stdio.